# RequestMapping in Controller in Spring MVC in getting changed sometimes

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to implement Spring MVC in my web application and I have a controller class.

```
@Controller<br>
public class ContactController {
@Autowired<br>
private ContactService contactService; 

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String displayLoginPage(HttpServletRequest httpReq, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result){
    return "login";
}

/*Spring will automatically calls this method whenever it encounters "/home" url in request.*/
@RequestMapping("/login/home")
public String displayHomePage(HttpServletRequest httpReq, Map<String, Object> map){
    map.put("contact", new Contact());
    map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());
    return "contact";
}}
```

After launching the application, login screen comes up and then upon click of button, I am observing that value for RequestMapping is getting changed sometimes. Sometimes it is "/login/home" or sometimes it is "/home". Why this is not constant ? Is there any way so that I may know what will be the requestMapping so that I can forward it to corresponding method in controller ?

PS: In the login.jsp, I have code like below:
form action="home" commandName="login"

Comment: Your `action` is pointing **relatively** to `home`. So if the page that form is under `/login/`, the `home` will be `/login/home`. If the page is under `/whatever/`, the `home` will be `/whatever/home`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If form `action` doesn't begin with a slash (`/`), form is submitted to address relative to the current one.

If you are already on the `login` page (i.e. your current address already ends with `/login`) and you have specified `form action="home"`, form is submitted to current address with `home` appended at the end - so the result is `/login/home`, which maps to one of your controller methods.